# Resetting aurelia-validation after a successful submit

Tags: aurelia

I'm leveraging [aurelia-validation](https://github.com/aurelia/validation) for my app. What I would like to do is reset the form to empty values after a successful submission.

Here's my view class:

```
@inject(Validation)
export class Inquire {

    @ensure(isName)
    firstName = '';

    @ensure(isName)
    lastName = '';

    . . .

    constructor(validation) {
        this.validation = validation.on(this);
    };

    sendInquiry() {
        this.validation.validate()
            .then(() => {
                // make API call here, which works
                // reset fields
                this.firstName = '';
                . . .
            }).catch((validationResult) => {
                console.log(validationResult);
            });
    };
};
```

If I set the `firstName`, `lastName` and other fields back to empty strings, the form validation is re-triggered. How can I prevent this from happening?

It seems like you should be able to call `.clear()` or `.destroy()` on the `ValidationGroup` as [referenced here in the source code](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/master/src/validation-group.js), but that isn't working for me.

Comment: Calling `this.validation.clear()` after clearing out the fields is working fine for me... what do you mean on "isn't working for me" ? You see the validation errors or an error in the console?

Comment: Huh. I can't explain why it works now, but calling `.clear()` after setting the fields back to their default values **is** working. Weird!

Comment: Calling `.clear()` should be part of the documentation and examples.

Comment: We always welcome PR's to the docs :)  @nemesv can you post that as an answer?

Comment: I'll definitely be adding one. I *really* want to see Aurelia be successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ValidationGroup`'s `clear()` method should do the trick. The point is that you have to call this **after** you have cleared your fields:

```
sendInquiry() {
    this.validation.validate()
        .then(() => {

            // make API call here, which works
            // reset fields
            this.firstName = '';
            . . .

            //this resets the validation and clears the error messages
            this.validation.clear();

        }).catch((validationResult) => {
            console.log(validationResult);
        });
};
```

In newer Aurelia validation versions (after 2016 august) you need to use the `reset` method:

```
this.validation.reset()
```

See in the [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022051633/http://aurelia.io:80/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/12):

> The opposite of the `validate` method is `reset`. Calling reset with no arguments will unrender any previously rendered validation results. You can supply a reset instruction to limit the reset to a specific object or property:

> ```
> controller.reset();
> ```

```
controller.reset({ object: person });
controller.reset({ object: person, propertyName: 'firstName' });
```

Comment: In the newer release of Aurelia, this changed to `this.validation.reset()`.